# How to install mediapipe modules?

Tags: python, installation, module, mediapipe

I work in the Python. And I recently ran into the problem of installing modules. For example, how do I install a module for creating different effects as glasses?
Thanks

Comment: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/python.html

Comment: it this command: `pip install the_module_name`